# Trapezoidal Stability of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

I am getting confused when attempting to obtain the condition for stability of the differential equation $$\frac{d}{dt}(y)=\alpha$$. Like, the trapezoidal formula
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac1{2}h\left(f(t_n,y_n)+f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})\right)$$ reduces to $0=0$ for this case, when substituting the values of $y_i$ and $f(y_i,t_i)$. Any workarounds? Thanks beforehand.